# Guardar valor checked en base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<form method="post" id="check" name="check" action="">          
<?php if ($invoiceValues['estado']==4) { 
                    $value_c = 3; 
                }
                 if ($invoiceValues['estado']==3) {
                    $value_c = 4;
                }
            ?>
                        <div class="form-check form-switch" style="padding-left:0px">
                          <dt class="float-start"><label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Marcar casilla</label></dt>
                          <dd class="float-end"><input class="form-check-input" onchange="this.form.submit()" value="<?php echo $value_c; ?>" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="marca_cobro" <?php if ($invoiceValues['estado']==4){ echo "checked";} ?> ></dd>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
                </form>
```

Si en la base de datos el campo contiene un "3" el `checkbox` está sin marcar, y si tiene un "4" está marcado.

Si el checkbox no está marcado y lo marco guarda satisfactoriamente en la base de datos el valor "4" para que en el front aparezca como marcado. Sin embargo, si desmarco el checkbox (pasando de 4 a 3) la base de datos no guarda nada y `value` se queda vacío.

No encuentro donde puede estar el problema.

Esta es la consulta para actualizar el valor de "estado" cada vez que se marca o se desmarca el checkbox.

```
<?php    
public function cobrar($POST){  
        $sqlInsert = "
            UPDATE ".$this->invoiceOrderTable." 
                SET estado = '".$POST['marca_cobro']."' 
                WHERE id = '".$POST['id']."'";      
            mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlInsert);    
    }
?>
```

Comment: Por diseño, las casillas de selección sin marcar no se envían en el formulario. Puedes manejar la ausencia de lado del servidor: `... estado = '". ($POST['marca_cobro'] ?? 3)."...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las casillas de verificación (checkboxes) se envían solo si están marcadas. Puedes usar [asignación ternaria](https://www.neoguias.com/if-abreviado-en-php-el-operador-ternario/) o el [operador de fusión null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) para asignar un valor predeterminado si la variable no existe.

Con el operador de fusión null:

```
public function cobrar($POST) {
    $estado = $POST['marca_cobro'] ?? 3;
    $sqlInsert = "UPDATE {$this->invoiceOrderTable}
        SET estado = '$estado' 
        WHERE id = '{$POST['id']}'";      
    mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlInsert);    
}
```

Adicionalmente, puedes incluir variables entre comillas dobles y PHP las va a interpretar; los elementos de arreglo y propiedades de objeto deben ir entre llaves ([sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta Cambiar el valor del value con JS antes de enviar el Formulario:

-Coloca una función que al cambiar actualice tu input con *Onchange*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="marca_cobro" name="marca_cobro" value="3" onchange="verificar()">
```

Por ejemplo:

```
function verificar()
{

  if (document.getElementById('marca_cobro').checked)
  {
      document.getElementById('marca_cobro').value=4;
  }
  else
  {
        document.getElementById('marca_cobro').value=3;
  }
  
  alert("Valor es: "+document.getElementById('marca_cobro').value);

}
```

Acá te dejo un funcional, con eso antes de enviarse se actualiza tu checkbox

```js
function verificar()
{

  if (document.getElementById('marca_cobro').checked)
  {
      document.getElementById('marca_cobro').value=4;
  }
  else
  {
        document.getElementById('marca_cobro').value=3;
  }
  
  alert("Valor es: "+document.getElementById('marca_cobro').value);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="marca_cobro" name="marca_cobro" value="3" onchange="verificar()">
```